# Looking for shorter code in C for incrementing array

Tags: arrays, c, function, increment

Is there shorter/faster code in C for incrementing array?

```
void arrayIncrement(int array[], int size, int increment) {
    for (; size >= 0; size--) {
        array[size] += increment;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think any space you save will be at the cost of readability from this point. 5 lines is not significant.

Comment: If `size` is really the size of the array then you are invoking *undefined behavior*  on the first iteration, by accessing one past the end. And if the caller always has to pass `size - 1` then it's a very unconventional API

Comment: `while(size--) array[size] +=increment;`

Answer (score 3):

Your code actually has undefined behavior because you increment `array[size]` which is the element beyond the end of the array.

Note also that `size` should have type `size_t` to allow for very large arrays on 64-bit systems.

You should either decrement `size` before incrementing the array element:

```
void arrayIncrement(int array[], size_t size, int increment) {
    while (size-- > 0) {
        array[size] += increment;
    }
}
```

Or increment the `array` pointer:

```
void arrayIncrement(int array[], size_t size, int increment) {
    while (size-- > 0) {
        *array++ += increment;
    }
}
```

Or more readable: use an index variable:

```
void arrayIncrement(int array[], size_t size, int increment) {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        array[i] += increment;
    }
}
```